# Beginner explanation of Dueling Network Architectures for Deep Reinforcement Learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I cannot find a beginner explanation of the [*Dueling Network Architectures for Deep Reinforcement Learning*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06581) anywhere online.

Most resources are rather advanced, so could anyone help with a bit of newbie explanation of how the calculations happen in a Dueling Network?

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/improvements-in-deep-q-learning-dueling-double-dqn-prioritized-experience-replay-and-fixed-58b130cc5682